# How can i keep write text in the code in a new line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using ToolTip and when i'm writing the text that will show it's getting too long to the right so i clicked enter to keep write the text in a new line it dosent mean when i'm running the program it will be in a new line this is only for me to see the text easier.

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox2, "Create automatic animated gif after rain event 
                                     this text is a new line");
```

Instead doing:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox2, "Create automatic animated gif after rain event this text is a new line");
```

I just want to see what i'm writing more easy.

For example what i mean is:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox2, "Create automatic animated gif after rain event 
                                     this is text to keep writing
                                      and this is also the same line one single line to show");
```

So when i'm running the program i will see all the text ine long line but here in the visual studio i want to see the text in lines.

When doing:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox2, "Create automatic animated gif after rain event 
                                     text to add");
```

I'm getting 9 errors it's like the part: text to add is not inside the ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do this:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox2, "Create automatic animated gif " +
                                    "after rain event " + 
                                    "text to add");
```

Answer (score 1):

String literals in C# cannot span multiple lines. If you want to break your strings across multiple lines, then each line needs to be individually quoted and then you can concatenate them:

```
string str = "Create automatic animated gif after rain event " +
             "text to add";
```

Comment: This isn't totally correct - *regular* string literals cannot span multiple lines. Verbatim string literals, denoted by an @ before the "", can span multiple lines without the need for concatenation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Note that I didn't really do my due diligence. For the purpose of this, you're right - Taras B points out that the verbatim string literal will contain newlines instead of plain ol concatenations.

Comment: I was just looking into that because I was confused how it would deal with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

For better visual presentation you can also use [verbatim literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) with `@` prefix:

```
var s = @"Create automatic animated gif after rain event 
this is text to keep writing
and this is also the same line one single line to show";
```

Note that it will also create 3 lines in the `s` variable, not just visually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have long texts, it might be easier to store them as string resource.

Right click the project in the solution explorer and select *Properties* > *Resources*. If you are adding resources for the first time to this project, click "... Click here to create one". Then enter a name for the string resource (e.g. "AnimatedGifToolTip") and a string value.

In the code you can use this string resource like this:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox2, Properties.Resources.AnimatedGifToolTip);
```